# Regarding the Execution of Apex class

Tags: apex

Hi I am executing the some piece of code I am facing this Error:

```
 if(!Account_Address__c.sObjectType.getDescribe().isDeletable())
        {
ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,Label.Address_Delete_Not_Allowed)); 
            return;
        }
```

> Error: Compile Error: Invalid external string name:
>   address_delete_not_allowed

Where i want to add error Messages in our edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you haven't created your Label "Address_Delete_Not_Allowed", to do that go to setup>custom labels and create a label with that name, once you do it it should works fine

Answer (score 0):

You should have a custom label named:

Address_Delete_Not_Allowed

And that should work fine